# Filter the_posts doesn't work on search page

Tags: loop, filters, search

In a plugin, I have this simple code:

```
add_filter( 'the_posts', 'process_search_results', 10, 2 );
function process_search_results($posts, $query=false) {
    print_r($posts);
    return $posts;
}
```

This shows the list of posts that will be looped over in the loop. But on a search page, an empty array (`Array()`) is printed, while the search results are still shown. Why is `$posts` empty for searches?

Some background: I'll try to code a custom search plugin that should merge results from an external data source into the default results.

Comment: I have the plugin Relevanssi installed, that also hooks into `the_posts`. So changing the filter priority from 10 to 20 gives me the post list even on search pages. How embarrassing ...